# Prevent backward navigation in angular app (mobile)

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to prevent the user from backward navigation in some parts of an app I am building. So far I am using this method:

```
ngOnInit() { 

 history.pushState(null, null, location.href);   
 window.onpopstate = function(event) {
   history.go(1);
 };
}

ngOnDestroy() {
 window.onpopstate = function(event) {
   history.go();
 };
}
```

This is working great except on iOS chrome and safari. I've also tried:

```
history.replaceState(null, document.title, location.pathname);
```

in ngOnInit with not luck. Can someone enlighten my on how browsers on these mobile devices are using history and/or popstate differently than on windows/macOS versions of browsers?

Comment: That's doing something against user, so even if you get it working for all environments, it can change with new browser versions. Have you considered using canDeactivate auth guard displaying dialog like "Your data will be lost when you leave the page, are you sure?" instead?

Comment: I think this is not possible for security reasons. Think about the annoying things scammers could do when this would be possible.

Comment: Which version of Angular?

Comment: @DanielKucal Yes, I did a POC with that but was not happy with the User interaction. I much prefer preventing backward navigation and messaging to the user that it is "disabled" and direct them what to do.

Comment: @BeetleJuice 4.3.1

Comment: ok I wrote up how I would approach this

Answer (score 4):

Instead of trying to implement different browser-specific solutions, I would think about Angular's [`CanDeactivate` guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#candeactivate-handling-unsaved-changes).

Suppose you have a service (let's call it `NavigatorService`) that always stores the previous route:

```
@Injectable()
export class NavigatorService{
  private previousRoute:string = null;
  private currentRoute:string = null;
  /** Listen to and log new route paths */
  constructor(private router:Router){
    router.events.filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe(
      e => {
        this.previousRoute = this.currentRoute;
        this.currentRoute = e['url'];
      }
    )
  }
  /** Checks whether the next route corresponds to the previous route  */
  isGoingBack(nextState:RouterStateSnapshot){                   
      return nextState.url === this.previousRoute;
  }
}
```

Next create a CanDeactivateGuard that will rely on this service to determine whether to allow the user to navigate away from the current view:

```
@Injectable()
export class BackwardGuard implements CanDeactivate<any> {
  // Inject the service needed
  constructor(navigatorService:NavigatorService){}

  // Angular 4 provides these arguments to any CanDeactivate guard
  // see https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate#interface-overview
  canDeactivate(component:any, currentRoute:ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
             currentState:RouterStateSnapshot, nextState:RouterStateSnapshot){                   
      // Allow navigation only if the user is not going back
      return !this.navigatorService.isGoingBack(nextState);
  }
}
```

Finally, register this guard on the routes whose components you want to protect from backwards navigation:

```
appRoutes:Routes = [
  {
    path: 'some-path',
    component: ProtectedComponent,
    canDeactivate: [BackwardGuard]
  }
];
```

There may be bugs in this untested code, but I think once you iron them out, it should work. Remember to provide `NavigatorService` to your component's module (e.g: `AppModule`) and to provide `BackwardGuard` to the matching routing module (e.g.: `AppRoutingModule`)

Comment: I went down this route before but bailed because I couldn't figure out how to get the current route ( I think). I believe i am seeing the same thing with your implementation. I am getting the error: "Cannot find name 'RouterEvent'." Has the api changed and do you know what to do?

Comment: `RouterEvent` has to be imported from `@angular/router`. [See the docs](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterEvent)

Comment: Pretty sure that is only in the new 5.0.1. I can't import it with 4.3.1.

Comment: Ok forget that. Just remove it from the code, so that `(e:RouterEvent) =>` becomes `e =>`. The rest should still work as advertised.  Access properties like `e['url']`

Comment: Yes, If you click back once. Which proves out the concept at least. Doing further debugging now.